# How to output SQL data onto a QTableQWidget in the style of a timetable

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to output my database as it is onto a QTableWidget. I am quite new to Qt designer and Pyqt as well. I have never used a tablewidget before and was wondering if it is possible to achieve my question?

My code at the moment is just the translated code from QT Designer to PYQT5 and I am just showing you the code so you know the variables for the tables.

I have researched and I can't find anything similar to my question so I am just asking for an expert to see if this is possible and help me to finish this project I'm doing.

My database

[image]

At the moment my page looks like this:

My Current Page

[image]

The code I am using is this.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Timetable.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery)



class Ui_Timetable(object):
    def setupUi(self, Timetable):
        Timetable.setObjectName("Timetable")
        Timetable.resize(1201, 988)
        Timetable.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1201, 988))
        Timetable.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(91, 155, 213);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Timetable)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.frame)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 950))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1161, 948))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Header = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Header.setStyleSheet("font: 75 20pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.Header.setObjectName("Header")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Header, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.HomeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.HomeButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.HomeButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.HomeButton.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/pngtree-vector-house-icon-png-image_695726 (1).jpg);")
        self.HomeButton.setText("")
        self.HomeButton.setObjectName("HomeButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.HomeButton, 0, 1, 2, 1)

        self.Week1label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week1label.setObjectName("Week1label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week1label, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Week1Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week1Table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Week1Table.setObjectName("Week1Table")
        self.Week1Table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.Week1Table.setRowCount(4)

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week1Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)

        self.Week1Table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(155)
        self.Week1Table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.Week1Table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.Week1Table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.Week1Table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(60)
        self.Week1Table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.Week1Table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week1Table, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Week2Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week2Label.setObjectName("Week2Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week2Label, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week2Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week2Table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Week2Table.setObjectName("Week2Table")
        self.Week2Table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.Week2Table.setRowCount(4)

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()

        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(155)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(60)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week2Table, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week3Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week3Label.setObjectName("Week3Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week3Label, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week3Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week3Table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Week3Table.setObjectName("Week3Table")
        self.Week3Table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.Week3Table.setRowCount(4)

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)

        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(155)
        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(60)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week3Table, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        Timetable.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Timetable)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Timetable)

    def retranslateUi(self, Timetable):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Timetable.setWindowTitle(_translate("Timetable", "Timetable"))
        self.Header.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Weekly Timetable"))
        self.Week1label.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Week 1"))
        item = self.Week1Table.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week1Table.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week1Table.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week1Table.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Monday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Tuesday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Wednesday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Thursday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Friday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Saturday"))
        item = self.Week1Table.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Sunday"))
        self.Week2Label.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Week 2"))
        item = self.Week2Table.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week2Table.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week2Table.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week2Table.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Monday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Tuesday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Wednesday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Thursday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Friday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Saturday"))
        item = self.Week2Table.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Sunday"))
        self.Week3Label.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Week 3"))
        item = self.Week3Table.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week3Table.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week3Table.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week3Table.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "New Row"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Monday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Tuesday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Wednesday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Thursday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Friday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Saturday"))
        item = self.Week3Table.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("Timetable", "Sunday"))














import images

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Timetable = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Timetable()
    ui.setupUi(Timetable)
    Timetable.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work and i thought i'd post this so anyone else who needs help with a question similar they can use my code. Just replace my database name with yours.

```
        timetabledb = sqlite3.connect("Timetabledatabase.db")
        timetableconnection = timetabledb.cursor()
        timetableconnection.execute("SELECT * FROM Week1")
        week1timetable = timetableconnection.fetchall()
        week1timetable = list(week1timetable)

        y = 0
        z = 0
        week1timetableLength = len(week1timetable)

        while y != week1timetableLength:
            row = week1timetable[y]
            row = list(row)

            monday = row[0]
            monday = str(monday)
            tuesday = row[1]
            tuesday = str(tuesday)
            wednesday = row[2]
            wednesday = str(wednesday)
            thursday = row[3]
            thursday = str(thursday)
            friday = row[4]
            friday = str(friday)
            saturday = row[5]
            saturday = str(saturday)
            sunday = row[6]
            sunday = str(sunday)

            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 0)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", monday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 1)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", tuesday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 2)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", wednesday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 3)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", thursday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 4)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", friday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 5)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", saturday))
            item = self.Week1Table.item(z, 6)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", sunday))

            z = z + 1
            y = y + 1



        self.Week2Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week2Label.setObjectName("Week2Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week2Label, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week2Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week2Table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Week2Table.setObjectName("Week2Table")
        self.Week2Table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.Week2Table.setRowCount(4)

        a = 0
        while a != 4:
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 0, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 1, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 2, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 3, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 4, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 5, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week2Table.setItem(a, 6, item)
            a = a + 1

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()

        self.Week2Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(155)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.Week2Table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(60)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.Week2Table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)

        timetabledb = sqlite3.connect("Timetabledatabase.db")
        timetableconnection = timetabledb.cursor()
        timetableconnection.execute("SELECT * FROM Week2")
        week2timetable = timetableconnection.fetchall()
        week2timetable = list(week2timetable)

        y = 0
        z = 0
        week2timetableLength = len(week2timetable)

        while y != week2timetableLength:
            row = week2timetable[y]
            row = list(row)

            monday = row[0]
            monday = str(monday)
            tuesday = row[1]
            tuesday = str(tuesday)
            wednesday = row[2]
            wednesday = str(wednesday)
            thursday = row[3]
            thursday = str(thursday)
            friday = row[4]
            friday = str(friday)
            saturday = row[5]
            saturday = str(saturday)
            sunday = row[6]
            sunday = str(sunday)

            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 0)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", monday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 1)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", tuesday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 2)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", wednesday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 3)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", thursday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 4)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", friday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 5)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", saturday))
            item = self.Week2Table.item(z, 6)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", sunday))

            z = z + 1
            y = y + 1

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week2Table, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week3Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week3Label.setObjectName("Week3Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week3Label, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Week3Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.Week3Table.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Week3Table.setObjectName("Week3Table")
        self.Week3Table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.Week3Table.setRowCount(4)

        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.Week3Table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)

        a = 0
        while a != 4:
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 0, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 1, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 2, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 3, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 4, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 5, item)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.Week3Table.setItem(a, 6, item)
            a = a + 1

        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(155)
        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(50)
        self.Week3Table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(60)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.Week3Table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Week3Table, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        Timetable.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        timetabledb = sqlite3.connect("Timetabledatabase.db")
        timetableconnection = timetabledb.cursor()
        timetableconnection.execute("SELECT * FROM Week3")
        week3timetable = timetableconnection.fetchall()
        week3timetable = list(week3timetable)

        y = 0
        z = 0
        week3timetableLength = len(week3timetable)

        while y != week3timetableLength:
            row = week3timetable[y]
            row = list(row)

            monday = row[0]
            monday = str(monday)
            tuesday = row[1]
            tuesday = str(tuesday)
            wednesday = row[2]
            wednesday = str(wednesday)
            thursday = row[3]
            thursday = str(thursday)
            friday = row[4]
            friday = str(friday)
            saturday = row[5]
            saturday = str(saturday)
            sunday = row[6]
            sunday = str(sunday)

            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 0)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", monday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 1)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", tuesday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 2)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", wednesday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 3)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", thursday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 4)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", friday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 5)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", saturday))
            item = self.Week3Table.item(z, 6)
            item.setText(_translate("Timetable", sunday))

            z = z + 1
            y = y + 1
```